# Possibility to use hyperlinks in a shared excel workbook

Tags: excel, hyperlink, tracking, shared

I've got an excel document where we've enabled the "Track Changes" functionality in order to capture whose changes what and when - for this you'd have to share the workbook.

We've now found that we want to make it a bit easier to navigate in the file (as it's getting quite big) - and in this process we'd like to make use of hyperlinks between tabs.

Now I've looked around a bit to find out how to do this - because as you may know Excel doesn't allow you to use hyperlinks when the workbook is shared (at least not that I know of) - and I don't want to - unshare workbook > insert hyperlink > reshare - as that means losing the tracking we've made so far :(

I've been able to find an answer stating:

In the Formula Bar for the cell you want the link in, use the following formula:
=HYPERLINK("url_goes_here", "cell_content_here")

Now I've tried inserting something like this:
=HYPERLINK("'CHANGE LOG'!"; "CHANGE LOG") and alternatively
=HYPERLINK("'CHANGE LOG'"; "CHANGE LOG")

It does truly insert a hyperlink but I just get an error message stating "cannot open the specified file."

Is anyone aware of a workaround or able to tell if I'm doing something completely wrong?

Br, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Several other sites suggests to unshare, add links and then reshare the workbook but this is somewhat annoying because it prevents users that currently have it open from properly saving if you unshare while they have it open even if you reshare before they save.

No need to unshare then reshare just set the cell's `Formula` property to equal to `=HYPERLINK(link, text)`

```
Sheets(targetSheet).Range(targetRange).Formula = _
    "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "http://www.google.ca/" & Chr(34) & ", " _
    & Chr(34) & "Click to go to google" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Chr(34) are double quotes

The result formula is `=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.ca/", "Click to go to google")`

This is the workaround in VBA to allow hyperlinks in shared workbooks.

Sorry that this probably doesn't completely answer OP's question but this was the only SO topic regarding this problem so I thought I'd share in case anyone else stumbles here.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010342583.aspx

Section: Jump to a specific cell on a worksheet